# How to use html js library inside react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an HTML page which has some Javascript library how I can use them in React App. Do I need to import them directly and it will be functional which I suppose wrong So How I can do that properly?

NOTE: I'm using React v9.5.0.

```html
<!-- All Jquery -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <script src="./assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="./assets/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
    <script src="./assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/extra-libs/sparkline/sparkline.js"></script>
    <!--Wave Effects -->
    <script src="./dist/js/waves.js"></script>
    <!--Menu sidebar -->
    <script src="./dist/js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
    <!--Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="./dist/js/custom.min.js"></script>
    <!-- this page js -->
    <script src="./assets/extra-libs/multicheck/datatable-checkbox-init.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/extra-libs/multicheck/jquery.multicheck.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/extra-libs/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        /****************************************
         *       Basic Table                   *
         ****************************************/
        $('#zero_config').DataTable();
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried that? You should execute `.DataTable()` after DOM is loaded, not before.

Comment: my main problem is How you import js files in React app to use them ?

As for the DataTable i think need to use componentDidMount if i'm not wrong

Comment: Many of the libraries you've included (bootstrap, jquery, etc) can be installed as dependencies via npm or yarn. You'd then be able to easily import them into your components. It's also easier to manage that way.

Comment: Yes, understand that very well but there is custom js library which i want to use instead of creating them from scratch again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your necessary folders for css or js in the location where your index.html file is present.

```
├── css
│   └── style.css
├── js
│   └── script.js
└── index.html
```

And inside your index.html file, refer those files like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/style.css"/>

<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

This will do.

**EDIT :**

You can refer public folder from your app components using the `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` variable. To give you an example of accessing a CSS file inside `public/css` folder from your `App` component,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/css/style.css'}/>
```

Also, check out the docs [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) for more details.

Comment: I'm using React app so i'm doing this inside App.js not HTML file.

Comment: I was telling for React only. If you want the static files tobe visible to all your components, then, adding to your index.html is preferrable. But if you want to apply to only a component then go like this "import styles from './style.css';" to your component

Comment: in react project there is no index.html only index.js - Is this fine ?

Comment: index.html is in the public folder

Comment: There is a index.html file in your public folder.

Comment: Thanks works fine. Q: How i can refer to a file inside public folder from App.js ?

Comment: @Neo Q: How i can refer to a file inside public folder from App.js ?

Comment: I have edited the answer and added the code to access public folder from App. Check out the details.